# Pandas read_csv() taking the last row as col header instead of first?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file over 70,000 rows using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", encoding='ISO 8859-1')
```

In this CSV file, the first row contains my column headers. However, when I run the above code and df.info(), I see that the DF headers are taking the last row of my CSV file. Also, instead of having 70,000 rows of data in the DF, there are only 146 rows.

What could be the reason that this is happening? It is odd because the same csv file and script work perfectly fine for my co-worker. Many thanks for your help please! :)

Comment: It will be difficult to answer without a sample of the file…